# How to pass on the name of a variable in R

Tags: r, variables, environment-variables, global-variables

So, I'm making a function like

```
    example <- function(x, y){
z <- data.frame("variable name" = y, "Quantity of 1" = sum(x==1, na.rm = TRUE))
eval(as.character(y)) <<- z
}

list <- sample(c(0,1), size = 12, replace = TRUE)
```

If I evaluate my function using

```
example(list, "list")
```

It gives me an

```
error in eval(as.character(y)) <<- z: object 'y' not found
```

I want the function to give me a variable which I could find by the name I pass on it (as "Y") given that I'll have to work using the same procedures multiples times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `assign`:

```r
example <- function(x, y){
  z <- data.frame("variable name" = y, "Quantity of 1" = sum(x==1, na.rm = TRUE))
  assign(y, z, envir = parent.frame())
}

list <- sample(c(0,1), size = 12, replace = TRUE)

example(list, "list")

list
#>   variable.name Quantity.of.1
#> 1          list             5
```

However, please note that this is not a great idea. You should try to avoid writing functions that can over-write objects in the global environment (or other calling frame) as this can have unintended consequences and is not idiomatic R.

It would be better to have:

```
example <- function(x, y){
  data.frame("variable name" = y, "Quantity of 1" = sum(x==1, na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

and do

```r
list <- example(list, "list")
```

or, better yet:

```r
example <- function(x){
  data.frame("variable name" = deparse(substitute(x)), 
             "Quantity of 1" = sum(x==1, na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

So you can just do:

```r
list <- example(list)
```

Furthermore, it is a good idea to avoid using a common function name like `list` as a variable name.